# Share Raspberry pi's internet through router

Tags: internet

I have started internet in my Raspberry Pi using USB internet dongle. Then I have make connection of Raspberry Pi to router via LAN cable.

Now I want to share Internet on router. It means Those user who are connecting on "Router" can access internet which is running on "Raspberry Pi"

How can I achieve? Please help. I don't have an idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome -- but the precise brand of computers you are using is actually irrelevant to this question, which belongs on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).   You should do [some general reading on bridging first](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_Network_Connections) (note the *"Bridging with a wireless NIC"* section).

Answer (score 1):

Yo have got to set a Wifi AP - [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-WiFi-Access-Point-out-of-a-Raspberry/) - and tell the router to be a wireless client (maybe your router can't do it, it is easier with a wireless repeater), then the router will share connection with de Banana.

In other way, you can install openwrt - [Openwrt Wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/3gdongle) -, and share Internet via cable to router if it can get DHCP in any port.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is share your RPi's network connection.  In Linux this is called "IP masquerading".  There are a ton of articles out there.  I think [these instructions](http://www.glennklockwood.com/sa/rpi-wifi-bridge.php) accomplish what you're trying to do.  From that post, this is a script that configures `iptables`, the system on Linux that manages network connections:

```
#!/bin/sh
IPT=/sbin/iptables
LOCAL_IFACE=eth0
INET_IFACE=wlan0
INET_ADDRESS=192.168.1.98

# Flush the tables
$IPT -F INPUT
$IPT -F OUTPUT
$IPT -F FORWARD

$IPT -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Allow forwarding packets:
$IPT -A FORWARD -p ALL -i $LOCAL_IFACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $INET_IFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Packet masquerading
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INET_IFACE -j SNAT --to-source $INET_ADDRESS
```

Make sure you update `LOCAL_IFACE`, `INET_IFACE`, and `INET_ADDRESS` to match your RPi's configuration.

Save that file on your RPi, say `/usr/local/bin/iptables-setup` and run it once.  After, run the command `iptables-save` and you should see something like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [73:5085]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [72:6792]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [43:2584]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:278]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.98
COMMIT
```

Add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then run `sysctl --system`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```